# Does the filing fee for an LLC count as a business expense when paying taxes in the US?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, limited-liability-company

I formed an LLC this past year. Does the filing fee to form the LLC count as a business expense for tax purposes? What about for each reoccurring year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically filing fee is probably a "[startup cost](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p535/ch08.html#en_US_2012_publink1000208939)", but yes - its a kind of an expense. The yearly recurring fee is an expense.